Intuitionist perspectives on Greek mathematics
My question pertains to how intuitionist perspectives on the philosophy of mathematics might apply to Greek geometry and number theory. It seems that the standard examples given to justify the intuitionist point of view are ultimately rooted in ambiguities arising from 1) the arithmetization of the continuum or 2) assumptions about actual as opposed to potential infinities. However, given that the Greek tradition 1) establishes a fundamental separation between the study of number and continuous magnitudes (length, area, volume, etc.) and 2) rejects the notion of actual infinity, I am curious about whether there are any instances at all of results from Greek geometry and/or number theory that an intuitionist might find unsatisfactory in some way.
To be slightly more specific, perhaps I can request an example (if one exists) of a proposition derived from, say, Hilbert's axioms for Euclidean geometry that is provable in classical but not intutionistic logic.

The introduction of a duality is already Platonic, with the world of ideas as primary: Aristotle, arguably the actual father of western philosophy, is a naturalist as opposed to an idealist, where the separation persists, just the primality is opposite.  That said, contrary to what you seem to have surmised, it is Aristotle who introduced the distinction "potential" vs "actual": indeed, there is no such thing as a rejection of "actual infinity" in classical (Aristotelian) Greek philosophy.  But, in fact, Intuitionism (AFAIK) is not about a rejection of infinity, absolute or otherwise...

In my understanding mathematicians generally were all intuitionist/constructivist until Cantor.

@Rushi - really? Newton, Leibniz... all "constructivists"??

@JulioDiEgidio - re "there is no such thing as a rejection of "actual infinity" in classical (Aristotelian) Greek philosophy". See Infinity: "It would be hard to exaggerate the role played by Aristotle in the history of infinity. He articulated some essential conceptual distinctions that were to influence all subsequent discussions. He was a finitist in the sense that in his universe, everything is finite. The cosmos is finite, bodies are finite, geometrical segments are finite, each number is finite, etc. 1/2

However, there are processes that can be iterated indefinitely, giving rise to what he called ‘potential infinity’. He claimed in fact that “in a sense [the infinite] is and in a sense it is not.” (Phys. 3.6, 206a13–14)." 2/2

You acn see M. Beeson, Brouwer and Euclid (2017) for an interesting discussion about the issue: Is Euclid constructive?

@MauroALLEGRANZA  You are wrong, that is just the natural philosophy and I did mention "primality", but there is much more to Aristotle than just that: indeed the usual retort (to a ponderate history) is that "absolute infinity" in Aristotle equals "God": just saying...   BTW, also Rushi is quite right, for a reasonable meaning of "intuitionism"...  I won't add more, I won't do a two day research just to prove some historical obvious.

Meanwhile a question on eastern philosophies, about the meaning of life if you will, to which I had even given an answer, has been migrated to Hinduism... You guys are a calamity and an agent of the enemy, this is not just about abysmal incompetence...

@MauroALLEGRANZA It looks like this paper offers some of the insights that I am searching for. Many thanks for the suggestion!

You are welcome :-)

@MauroALLEGRANZA This discussion tends to be anachronistic because terms like intuitionsim/constrictivism did not exist in the time of Newton etc. But if I take the essential sense of intuitionism it has (1) suspicion of non kosher uses of LEM/existential proofs (2) suspicion of completed infinity.  Where do you find these in Newton, Leibniz etc? I dont believe that infinitesimals count because they are just small numbers (speaking v informally) small enough that 2nd order terms vanish. ie. if x is small x² can be ignored (1/2)..

The only borderline case I can think of is infinite powerseries (Taylor series, generating functions etc). I write that off as simply waiting for the right formality/formalism to validate. But I'd be interested to hear if you can think of more substantive examples (2/2)
